# Perl replace specified space with underscore in array

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have an array that is returned after running a command line and consists of 4 items. For example:

```
ProjectA: i love perl c_iloveperl License: ab123
ProjectB: i_love_perl c_iloveperl License: ab123

Item1 = ProjectA:
Item2 = i love perl  /  i_love_perl
Item3 = c_iloveperl  
Item4 = License: ab123
```

Question:
How can I use `Perl`/`Sed` to replace specific empty space with underscore for Item2 only?
At the end, i will only need to get Item2 and Item3 with no empty space.

```
i_love_perl c_iloveperl
```

Any idea/suggestion? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: try `sed '/Item2/ s/ /_/g'`

Comment: Please post sample output in code tags too in your posts.

Comment: I'm sorry, how to get Item2? when i try to run `cut -d ' ' -f 2,3` it returned me `i love`. The output that I want is `i_love_perl c_iloveperl`

Comment: Read what makes a [mcve]. Your audience is left to assume the answers to the below questions  1. `I have an array` - Is it a bash array? 2. `Item2 = i love perl  /  i_love_perl` Does it mean `Item2` can contain either of those? Before posting questions, it is always better to contemplate on it in a reader's angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure still, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/^Project/{sub(/[^ ]* /,"");sub(/ License.*/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
i love perl c_iloveperl
i_love_perl c_iloveperl
```

Code will look for a line which is starting from string `Project` and then will print the things between first space and string `License` Let us know how it goes then.

***EDIT:*** As OP needs to have string `Project` also in output so following may help in same.

```
awk '/^Project/{sub(/[^ ]* /,"");sub(/ License.*/,"");if(NF>2){sub(/ /,"_")};if(NF>2){sub(/ /,"_")};print}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
i_love_perl c_iloveperl
i_love_perl c_iloveperl
```

Comment: Wow. It is working like a charm. But, I would like to have the output like this: `i_love_perl c_iloveperl` and `i_love_perl c_iloveperl` for both **ProjectA** and **ProjectB**. I want to replace empty space in between with underscore for **ProjectA**.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. The previous code result `echo 'ProjectA: i love perl c_iloveperl' | awk '/^Project/{sub(/[^ ]* /,"");sub(/ License.*/,"");print}` is what I want but just that, I want to replace empty space in between with underscore for **ProjectA** and **ProjectB** remained the same as in `i_love_perl c_iloveperl`. Eventually, the desired output that i want is there is 2 line of `i_love_perl c_iloveperl` . Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: I have edited the code in the answer. It works like a charm! This is the code `awk '/^Project/{sub(/[^ ]* /,"");sub(/ License.*/,"");if(NF>2){sub(/ /,"_")};if(NF>2){sub(/ /,"_")};print}'`

Comment: @IAMbeginner, glad that it helped you. But what you have edited? code looks same only to me?

Comment: i have added one more time of this part: `if(NF>2){sub(/ /,"_")}`.

Comment: @IAMbeginner, why you are adding 2 times condition? please explain.

Comment: I want to have empty space replaced by underscore. There is 2 occurrence time of empty space, so I added that to replace 2 times of empty space with underscore

Answer (score 0):

Below `sed` may help too. But,as I mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441369/perl-replace-specified-space-with-underscore-in-array#comment83903422_48441369) comment, your question is a bit terse in that it is difficult to figure out actual requirement.

```
echo "Item1 = ProjectA:
Item2 = i love perl
Item3 = c_iloveperl
Item4 = License: ab123" | sed -nE '/Item2/{N;s/Item[23] *= *//g;s/ /_/g;s/\n/ /;s/_*$//p}'
```

**Output**

```
i_love_perl c_iloveperl
```